# How can I create a elevated child process with inherited handles from his parent

Tags: c++, winapi, parent-child

I'm trying to create a child process with elevated rights in Windows (by trigerring a UAC prompt) and get this child process to inherit his parent STDOUT handle to be able to output back to the parent's console.

Additionnal Infos:

- Win32 APIs
- Im currently using `ShellExecuteEx()` with a `ShellExecuteInformation` that specifies a "runas" verb to trigger the UAC but any other solution that can create a elevated copy of the current running program (The child process is the same executable as the parent) but beeing able to output back to the parent's console.

Comment: Have a look at [Vista UAC: The Definitive Guide](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide). Start reading from "Routing via ShellExecuteEx()". He is doing redirection by using named pipes and an intermediate helper process that is created using `ShellExecuteEx` which in turn calls `CreateProcess` for being able to inherit the named pipe handles to the actual child process (if I understand correctly).

Comment: Yes @zett42 But this solution looks really hacky in my opinion...Im good at spagethi coding when im desperate but im not here yet :P

Comment: I don't think you will find an "easy" method for this. Once you start doing things out of the ordinary, UAC quickly gets messy. Anyway, if you fear spaghetti, just wrap all that mess into your own nifty interface. ;-)

Comment: If you are unable to modify the child process to send output to a designated console, you will need a proxy process to launch the child process on your behalf.  Run the proxy process elevated, and have it connect back to your console before it launches the child.  (Basically the same procedure as zett42 suggests, but simplified for your particular scenario.)

Comment: ... incidentally, I assure you that any solution that does not involve a proxy process will be even hackier!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ShellExecuteEx` with `runas` - The function `CreateProcessAsUserW` is called not from your process, but from `svchost.exe -k netsvcs` where `appinfo.dll` is running. And *bInheritHandles* is hardcoded to be *FALSE* - so
your process does not inherit any handles in this case. for making handles inheritable the only way is a direct call to `CreateProcessAsUserW` with a primary elevated token. But from where you got this token ? ok, you can run self exe second time as elevated (with `runas`) and duplicate elevated token back to original not-elevated process. but anyway (even with elevated token) - you need `SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME` privilege for call `CreateProcessAsUser`. but you have no this privilege.

Otherwise you could if you found some exploit.

The process handle, returned by `ShellExecuteEx` have no `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` access - So you can't use it for manual handle duplication later.

So in general - This is impossible by design

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the fact that `ShellExecuteEx()` is calling `svchost.exe` and that `bHinheritHandles` is hardcoded to `FALSE` I will investigate a workaround knowing this

Comment: The Application Information services creates the elevated process with an attribute to manually set the parent process to the client, so it could but does not support inheritance.  Also, there's another creation attribute that enables standard-handle duplication (not inheritance) when inheritance is disabled, but it's only used when a console app creates another console app attached to the same console. That's also unused here because the AppInfo service sets the creation flag to create a new console (for a new security context), which sets the child's standard handles to the new console.

Comment: @eryksun - yes, Application Information services use `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` for set process from which `ShellExecuteEx` was called as parent process. if it use also `bInheritHandles == TRUE` - new process will be inherit handles from our src process (where we called `ShellExecuteEx`) but not from `svchost.exe`. but `bInheritHandles` hardcoded to be false.

Comment: Even if it were possible by design, inheriting standard handles for another console isn't meaningful. What matters is the `ConsoleHandle` of the elevated process, which gets set up when it allocates the new console. The handles for the console input and screen buffer are only meaningful in the context of an attached console. The OP has another question where this was addressed. The elevated process has to call `FreeConsole` and `AttachConsole` to write to its parent's console -- or instead use an IPC scheme such as named pipes.